# jqGrid colmodel change in loadComplete

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

after 3 hours of googling I ask your help.

I have a jqGrid on a page.

grid's important options:

```js
$("#listU05").jqGrid({
url:'u05json.json', 
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'POST',

colModel :[ 
    {name:'Thema', index:'Thema', width:55},
....
loadComplete: function(data) {
   jQuery("#listU05").jqGrid.setColProp('Thema',
            {
                stype: 'select',
                searchoptions: {
                    value:"a:a;b:b"
                }
            }
);
```

after data loaded I have [Loading...] rectangle on my grid and no any reaction to code.
I see in debugger that code is active but I have no any visible result in colModel, and I have the rectangle.

What is the problem?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**UPDATED**: Current used code which still not work is below

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title><spring:message code="u05.TITLE"/></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


var getUniqueNames = function(grid, columnName, data, dataIndex) {
//     var data = grid.getGridParam('data');
     var uniqueTexts = [], text, textsMap = {}, i;

     for (i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
         text = data.rows[i].cell[dataIndex];
        if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
             textsMap[text] = true;
            uniqueTexts.push(text);
        }
    }
    return uniqueTexts;
}

buildSearchSelect = function(uniqueNames) {
    var values=":All";
    $.each (uniqueNames, function() {
        values += ";" + this + ":" + this;
    });
    return values;
}

setSearchSelect = function(grid, columnName, data, dataIndex) {
    grid.setColProp(columnName,
                {
                    stype: 'select',
                    searchoptions: {
                        value:'a:a',
                        sopt:['eq']
                    }
                });
}

  $("#listU05").jqGrid({
    url:'u05json.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:[
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.Thema"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.SubThema"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.status1"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.wie"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.KW"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.Jahr"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.kampagne"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.ergebnis"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.B1"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.B2"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.personal"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.qualifikation"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.iv"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.objekt"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.NR"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.ObjektArt"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.vorname"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.name"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.Z1"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.Z2"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.Z3"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.Z4"/>',
          '<spring:message code="u05.Column.team"/>'   
    ],
    colModel :[
          {name:'Thema', index:'u_05_01.Thema', width:55},
          {name:'u_05_01.SubThema', index:'u_05_01.SubThema', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${subThemaOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.status1', index:'u_05_01.status1', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${status1Options}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.wie', index:'u_05_01.wie', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${wieOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.KW', index:'u_05_01.KW', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${kwOptions}" }},
          {name:'Jahr', index:'u_05_01.Jahr', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${jahrOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.kampagne', index:'u_05_01.kampagne', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${kampagneOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.ergebnis', index:'u_05_01.ergebnis', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${ergebnisOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.B1', index:'u_05_01.B1', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${b1Options}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.B2', index:'u_05_01.B2', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${b2Options}" }},
          {name:'u_03.personal', index:'u_03.personal', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${personalOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_03.qualifikation', index:'u_03.qualifikation', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${qualifikationOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_03.iv', index:'u_03.iv', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${ivOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.objekt', index:'u_05_01.objekt', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${objektOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.NR', index:'u_05_01.NR', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${nrOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.ObjektArt', index:'u_05_01.ObjektArt', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${objektArtOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_06.vorname', index:'u_06.vorname', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${vornameOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_06.name', index:'u_06.name', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${nameOptions}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.Z1', index:'u_05_01.Z1', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${z1Options}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.Z2', index:'u_05_01.Z2', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${z2Options}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.Z3', index:'u_05_01.Z3', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${z3Options}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.Z4', index:'u_05_01.Z4', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${z4Options}" }},
          {name:'u_05_01.team', index:'u_05_01.team', width:55, stype: 'select', searchoptions:{ value:":\*All${teamOptions}" }}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:100,
    rowList:[10,50,100],
    sortname: 'u_05_01.Thema',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
     height: "400px",   
    caption: '<spring:message code="u05.TITLE"/>',
     loadComplete: function(data) {      
    $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'Thema',
                {
                    stype: 'select',
                    searchoptions: {
                        value:"a:a"
                    }
                });

     }   
  });

     jQuery("#listU05").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:false});
     jQuery("#listU05").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});

     // Loop for each select element on the page.
     $("select").each(function() {     
         // Keep track of the selected option.
         var selectedValue = $(this).val();

         // Sort all the options by text. I could easily sort these by val.
         $(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
             return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
         }));

         // Select one option.
         $(this).val(selectedValue);
     });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
     <form:form method="post" commandName="filterU05" action="u05" name="formU05">
<div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-jqgrid">
          <table>
               <tr>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.objekt"/>/<spring:message code="u05.Filter.Obj_Nr"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:input path="objekt" style="width:130px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
                    <form:input path="obj_Nr" style="width:40px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.Jahr"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:input path="jahr" style="width:60px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.kampagne"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:select path="kampagne" items="${listKampagne}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="value" style="width:180px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               <td rowspan="3">
                    <input type="submit" name="doFilter" value="filter" style="width:60px; height:60px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.wie"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:input path="wie" style="width:80px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.KW"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:input path="kw" style="width:60px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.ergebnis"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:select path="ergebnis" items="${listErgebnis}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="value" style="width:180px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.ObjektArt"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:select path="objektArt" items="${listObjektTyp}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="value" style="width:180px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.status1"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:select path="status1" items="${listStatus1}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="value" style="width:60px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.name"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:select path="u06_name" items="${listName}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="value" style="width:180px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><spring:message code="u05.Filter.team"/></td>
               <td>
                    <form:select path="team" items="${listTeam}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="value" style="width:180px" class="ui-widget-content"/>
               </td>                        
               </tr>              
          </table>         
</div>
<br>
     <table id="listU05"><tr><td/></tr></table>
     <div id="pager"></div>
<br>    
<div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-jqgrid">    
     <table class="InputForm">
     <tr><td>
     <input type="submit" name="doExcel" value="Excel" style="width:60px" onClick="document.formU05.action='u05excel';return true;" class="ui-widget-content"/>
     </td></tr>
     </table>
</div>    
     </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Loading..." which is not disappear means typically that an exception occur during of the filling of the grid or executing some callback functions like `loadComplete`. In you case the error was that you use `jQuery("#listU05").jqGrid.setColProp` instead of `jQuery("#listU05").setColProp` or `jQuery("#listU05").jqGrid('setColProp', ...`.

You can use the code of `loadComplete` to

```js
loadComplete: function(data) {
    $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'Thema', {
        stype: 'select',
        searchoptions: {
            value:"a:a;b:b"
        }
    });
}
```

I recommend you additionally to consider to use `beforeProcessing` for such operations. In case of setting searching properties of `colModel` it is not really important, but if you want use [formatter:'select'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#formatter_type_select) and load the `editoptions.value` from the server then usage of `beforeProcessing` is exactly correct place. The data returned from the server are not yet processed. So you can change `value` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) and **already during the current processing of the data** the `value` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) will be used by `'select'` formatter.

Comment: Oleg, thanks. Now I have no an exception... But I have no result: `code`  loadComplete: function(data) {   
    $(this).jqGrid('setColProp','Thema',
                {
                    stype: 'select',
                    searchoptions: {
                        value:'a:a',
                        sopt:['eq']
                    }
                });

 } `code`

Comment: @mad: I don't know where you have the problem. I suppose that you use it in wrong way. I just tested my suggestion on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchOnEnter1.htm). I set additional "XXX" value in the select of the 'Shipped via' column. Just open the searching dialog, then choose 'Shipped via' column and verify that there are 'XXX' in the select. If you don't find your error yourself you should append your question with **more full JavaScript code which you use now**.

Comment: thanks. I'm newby in jQuery. So it is possible I have some stupid error. But I see in lot of example and can't see it. Pls look at my code: [code in evernote page](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s144/sh/5352aa8c-2a85-4da9-99c1-ab5b62e4eeee/1c377f4f7bfd4d5e20fc5a717ba12e89). Honestly I try to realize your example with local autofilter (like in excel). I seen the example in previous post. And now I need the same on my page.

Comment: @mad: It's better if you always click ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) link under the question and append new information after the words like **"UPDATED"**. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) you can read how easy you can format the code. After 0.5 min looking at the code it was clear what you have the problem: you use `filterToolbar` after the grid having `datatype: 'json'`. So the `filterToolbar` will be constructed **before** the `loadComplete` are executed and the `searchoptions.value` will be set. You should call `filterToolbar` **later**.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Next time I will be in Hannover I will try to arrive to your city to shake your hand. Jokingly :) You saved lot of my time and nerves.